# How to know which keys are pressed in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

How would I know what keys are currently being pressed in SDL2 (not event)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)[SDL_SCANCODE_???]) {/*the key is held*/}
```

where `???` is a key name, one of [those](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode).